# How to perform seam carving on an image using PHP's GD library?

Tags: php, image, gd, resize, seam-carving

I am working on a project that resizes images using [PHP's GD](http://us.php.net/gd) library. I would like to be able to add the option to use [seam carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving) to resize images but don't want to require something like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (which can do seam carving with [its liquid rescale feature](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale)) to accomplish this.

Since there are no built-in seam carving functions in GD, **is there a way to perform seam carving on an image using PHP's GD library** or other built-in PHP functions?  Alternatively, do you know if seam carving will eventually be baked into GD?

Comment: Can't be very fast, but would love to see it done!

Comment: There is some AS3 code @ http://drawlogic.com/2007/09/04/as3-content-aware-resizing-or-image-seam-carving/

Comment: There is a JavaScript version too:  http://labs.pimsworld.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/demo-content-aware-image-resizing-2/

Answer (score 2):

While you could implement this using GD, you're best bet if you can control the server environment is to create an external script/program to carve an image. PHP is going to be a huge bottleneck doing those kind of calculations. Even basic matrix transformations run a serious risk of hitting the max execution times set in PHP configs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it shouldn't be possible with GD, but I can tell you it would be slow.

Imagemagick is open source, so I guess you could translate the function to PHP.